# Android PhoneGap and CSS translate3d

Tags: android, css, cordova, iscroll4

I'm trying to apply -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0) to an image in an Android PhoneGap app. I'm using iScroll4 for pinch-zoom on the image. The same exact CSS works great on iOS, but it is clear that the Android webview is not applying this to the image correctly (the image remains blocky and does not scale well at all).

The strange thing is that if I open the same file in the Android browser (NOT in PhoneGap) it works fine. This happens with Android 2 and 4. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

use `-webkit-transform:translate(x,y)` to change position and `-webkit-transform:scale(x,y)` to change size, 
translate3D(0,0,0) is more concerned with hardware acceleration.